# Slow performance with recursive SQL (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, common-table-expression

Sorry if this is a bit of a long question but there is no simple way to express it.

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    S.*
FROM 
    Stock S
LEFT JOIN 
    Stock_Category SC ON SC.StockId = S.Id
WHERE 
    S.Published = 1 
    AND (@CategoryId IS NULL OR 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM GetParentCategoriesByCategoryId(SC.CategoryId) 
          WHERE Id = @CategoryId) > 0)
```

Inside the `GetParentCategoriesByCategoryId()`, I have the following common table expression (CTE):

```
DECLARE @TableOutput TABLE(Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
                            PosDissectionId INT,
                            PosFamilyClassId INT,
                            ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                            Code NVARCHAR(25),
                            [Name] NVARCHAR(100),
                            Description NVARCHAR(1000),
                            AzureId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                            Extension NVARCHAR(10),
                            Visible BIT,
                            OrderIndex INT,
                            StockCount INT,
                            Depth INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalVisible INT,
            @TotalRows INT

    ;WITH CategoryStructure (Id, ParentId, ParentName, Name, Depth, Visible)
    As 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            C.Id, 
            C.ParentId, 
            CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS ParentName, 
            C.Name, 
            0 AS Depth, 
            C.Visible
        FROM 
            Category C
        WHERE 
            Id = @LocalCategoryId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            ParentCategory.Id, 
            ParentCategory.ParentId, 
            CategoryStructure.Name AS ParentName, 
            ParentCategory.Name, 
            CategoryStructure.Depth + 1,
            ParentCategory.Visible
        FROM 
            Category ParentCategory
        INNER JOIN 
            CategoryStructure ON ParentCategory.Id = CategoryStructure.ParentId
    )
    INSERT INTO @TableOutput
        SELECT          
            C.*,
            SC.StockCount,
            CS.Depth
        FROM 
            CategoryStructure CS 
        INNER JOIN 
            Category C ON  C.Id = CS.Id
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS StockCount 
             FROM Stock_Category SC
             INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Id = SC.StockId
             WHERE S.Published = 1 AND 
                 ((S.WidthMM IS NOT NULL AND 
                   S.HeightMM IS NOT NULL AND 
                   S.DepthMM IS NOT NULL AND
                    S.WeightG IS NOT NULL)) AND
                CategoryId IN(SELECT CategoryId FROM CategoryStructure)
        GROUP BY CategoryId

    ) SC ON SC.CategoryId = CS.Id

    WHERE (@IncludeSelf = 1 OR CS.Id != @CategoryId) 

    SELECT 
        @TotalVisible = SUM(CONVERT(INT, Visible)),
        @TotalRows = COUNT(*) 
    FROM @TableOutput

    IF @TotalVisible <> @TotalRows
        DELETE FROM @TableOutput    

    RETURN
END
```

**My query execution plan looks like this.**

[image]

Unfortunately I am getting over 7s long query times for 2000 rows. I believe I have added the correct indexes (and it appears to show that the query is using them).

I have been able to narrow the problem down to the LEFT JOIN in the CTE

```
   SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS StockCount 
   FROM Stock_Category SC
   INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Id = SC.StockId
   WHERE S.Published = 1 AND blah blah blah....
```

Because when I remove it performance drastically increases but that's all I can deduce so far.

I am not expecting a solution because I understand that its based on many factors but I am far from an SQL expert and am hoping someone could provide any guidance on what I might need to look for?

Schemas for tables can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpetq6fky58fhti/schemas.sql?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide sample data ,schema of tables involved

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: You may not want to `(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM GetParentCategoriesByCategoryId(SC.CategoryId) 
          WHERE Id = @CategoryId) > 0)` but instead `EXISTS (SELECT 1 from GetParentCategoriesByCategoryId(SC.CategoryId) WHERE Id = @CategoryId`. Furthermore, you probably want to get rid of that function call if you can.  Recursive CTE's are not fast.

Comment: Your multi-statement table valued function is hurting you here, I would re-write it as an in-line table valued function instead. [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx)

Comment: at least change this `(SELECT CategoryId FROM CategoryStructure)` adding a `NOLOCK` since you're joining itself.  There's a lot of restructuring you need to do with this.  @Rob Farley's right

Comment: @SQLMason Just to clarify, I am not Rob Farley. Rob Farley is the author of the article I provided a link to.

Comment: In your `schemas.sql`, you should switch your default constraint for `[Created] [datetime2](7)` to use `sysutcdatetime()`. `getutcdate()` returns `datetime`, `sysutcdatetime()` returns `datetime2(7)`

Comment: I can't really avoid using some sort of recursive CTE because I am traversing a tree and need to check if a given item exists within one of the nodes. Thank you all so much for your suggestions.

Comment: How many rows in Category?

Comment: @MartinSmith Category currently contains 419 rows, not tiny but certainly not huge. I would have expected many more for such poor results.

Comment: Instead of calling the multi statement TVF for each individual category id can you just materialise the whole hierarchy up front to get a result with all category id that meet your criteria then? And then use something like `SELECT S.* FROM  Stock S LEFT JOIN  Stock_Category SC ON SC.StockId = S.Id WHERE S.Published = 1 AND (@CategoryId IS NULL OR SC.CategoryId IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM #Cats)) OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: yeah, like @MartinSmith says, try to build all the results of that function up-front instead of looking it up for each category.

Comment: I could be incorrect but you can't materialize this query prior to running it. The primary cost of the query is actually in traversing the tree given the flat structure of a table, even if you cache your resultset you still need to traverse it to find your answer which in this case is All Parents of Category X. (I actually have two functions AllParentsOfX and AllChildrenOfX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for anyone curious the final solution involved redoing my indexes, utilising some of the suggestions from the comments above and importantly removing the temporary table.

In the end, I managed to get the query down to less than 1 second which was the goal. *But I am not really sure about the Group By, wondering if there is a better way to do it? Does anyone else have any further improvements?*

```
    WITH categorystructure (id, parentid, parentname, NAME, depth, visible) 
     AS (SELECT C.id, 
                C.parentid, 
                Cast('' AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS ParentName, 
                C.NAME, 
                0                         AS Depth, 
                C.visible 
         FROM   category C 
         WHERE  id = @CategoryId 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT ParentCategory.id, 
                ParentCategory.parentid, 
                categorystructure.NAME      AS ParentName, 
                ParentCategory.NAME, 
                categorystructure.depth + 1 AS Depth, 
                ParentCategory.visible 
         FROM   category ParentCategory 
                INNER JOIN categorystructure 
                        ON ParentCategory.id = categorystructure.parentid) 
SELECT C.*, 
       Isnull(SC.stockcount, 0) AS StockCount, 
       CS.depth 
FROM   categorystructure CS 
       INNER JOIN category C 
               ON C.id = CS.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT categoryid, 
                         Count(*) AS StockCount 
                  FROM   stock_category SC 
                         INNER JOIN stock S 
                                 ON S.id = SC.stockid 
                  WHERE  S.published = 1 
                         AND ( @AustPostShippingEnabled = 0 
                                OR ( S.widthmm IS NOT NULL 
                                     AND S.heightmm IS NOT NULL 
                                     AND S.depthmm IS NOT NULL 
                                     AND S.weightg IS NOT NULL ) ) 
                  GROUP  BY categoryid) SC 
              ON SC.categoryid = CS.id 
WHERE  ( @IncludeSelf = 1 
          OR CS.id != @CategoryId ) 
GROUP  BY C.id, 
          C.posdissectionid, 
          C.posfamilyclassid, 
          C.parentid, 
          C.code, 
          C.NAME, 
          C.description, 
          C.azureid, 
          C.extension, 
          C.visible, 
          C.orderindex, 
          SC.stockcount, 
          CS.depth 
HAVING Sum(CONVERT(INT, CS.visible)) = Count(*)
```

Comment: ```HAVING Sum(CONVERT(INT, CS.visible)) = Count(*)``` = ```WHERE CS.visible = cast(1 as bit)```, just saying :) And that will let you get rid of the group by.

Comment: @Anand Appreciate the suggestion but I don't believe you are correct. How does WHERE CS.visible = cast(1 as bit) accomplish the same thing as  Sum(CONVERT(INT, CS.visible)) = Count(*) ? Are you sure you understand the intention?

Comment: If you convert boolean to integer and sum the column on it, then compare to the number of records, the only way they will match is if all the rows are true. It's not that hard to see; also can you please upvote the useful answers please if you took suggestions from above? Thanks :)

Comment: What formatter do you use? Really good formatting there. It's not manual, is it?

Answer (score 1):

I've made 2 changes:

1) Make function inline (`HAVING` Clause)

2) Replace LEFT JOIN with outer apply.

```
WITH CategoryStructure (Id, ParentId, ParentName, Name, Depth, Visible)
As 
( 
    SELECT 
        C.Id, 
        C.ParentId, 
        CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS ParentName, 
        C.Name, 
        0 AS Depth, 
        C.Visible
    FROM 
        Category C
    WHERE 
        Id = @LocalCategoryId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        ParentCategory.Id, 
        ParentCategory.ParentId, 
        CategoryStructure.Name AS ParentName, 
        ParentCategory.Name, 
        CategoryStructure.Depth + 1,
        ParentCategory.Visible
    FROM 
        Category ParentCategory
    INNER JOIN 
        CategoryStructure ON ParentCategory.Id = CategoryStructure.ParentId
)
INSERT INTO @TableOutput
    SELECT          
        C.*,
        SC.StockCount,
        CS.Depth
    FROM 
        CategoryStructure CS 
    INNER JOIN 
        Category C ON  C.Id = CS.Id
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS StockCount 
         FROM Stock_Category SC
         INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Id = SC.StockId
         WHERE S.Published = 1 AND 
             ((S.WidthMM IS NOT NULL AND 
               S.HeightMM IS NOT NULL AND 
               S.DepthMM IS NOT NULL AND
                S.WeightG IS NOT NULL)) AND
            CategoryId = CS.Id
        ) SC

WHERE (@IncludeSelf = 1 OR CS.Id != @CategoryId) 
HAVING SUM(CONVERT(INT, Visible)) = COUNT(*)
```

P.S. First query looks strange (You have @CategoryId parameter, but do not seek by it. You build ALL possible trees then filter). I think you have mistake in your algorithm, is it possible write `GetParentCategoriesByCategoryId(@CategoryId)`?

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1. Change the in clause to an inner join:

   ```
   SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS StockCount 
   FROM Stock_Category SC
   INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Id = SC.StockId
   WHERE S.Published = 1 AND 
   ((S.WidthMM IS NOT NULL AND 
   S.HeightMM IS NOT NULL AND 
   S.DepthMM IS NOT NULL AND
   S.WeightG IS NOT NULL)) AND
   CategoryId IN(SELECT CategoryId FROM CategoryStructure)
   GROUP BY CategoryId
   ```

to -

```
SELECT CategoryId, COUNT(*) AS StockCount 
FROM Stock_Category SC
INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Id = SC.StockId
inner join CategoryStructure as CS
on CS.CategoryId = SC.CategoryId
WHERE S.Published = 1 AND 
((S.WidthMM IS NOT NULL AND 
S.HeightMM IS NOT NULL AND 
S.DepthMM IS NOT NULL AND
S.WeightG IS NOT NULL)) AND
GROUP BY CategoryId
```

2. Your query is mainly spending time on the index seek on IX_StockAllColumns. If it is indeed a non-clustered index on all columns, create a new non-clustered index on Published, WidthMM, HeightMM, DepthMM and WeightG columns.

Comment: I do not think you quite understand the original query, the question, the schema, or the table-valued function.

Comment: Replacing `IN` clause with `INNER JOIN` does not affect query plan